# Installing sql server ce 3.5 Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, setup-deployment

Ok my problem is simple i make a setup project for installing a simple application just as a practice it save to a database a name a last name and an ID.
But when installed it give me the exception error sql server ce 3.5 not installed i followed the instructions of some post with dlls and things like thata but doesnt work i want to know... how can i install  the sql ce 3.5 from my application setup. i mean calling the sql server ce installer in my setup or something like that.
Sorry for my bad english and thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article: [How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) should describe all the necessary steps.

It would be helpful if you could tell us the exact error message you are seeing.